# 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 while trying to install gevent-websocket

Tags: python, websocket, gevent

I'm trying to install gevent-websocket for Python (http://www.gelens.org/code/gevent-websocket/), but when I run easy_install gevent-websocket I get "command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1".

The following is the full output from the terminal.

```
tgarv@tommy-Studio-1537:~/Desktop/Code$ sudo easy_install gevent-websocket
install_dir /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/
Searching for gevent-websocket
Best match: gevent-websocket 0.3.4
Processing gevent_websocket-0.3.4-py2.6.egg
gevent-websocket 0.3.4 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gevent_websocket-0.3.4-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for gevent-websocket
Searching for gevent
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/gevent/
Reading http://www.gevent.org/
Reading http://gevent.org/
Best match: gevent 0.13.6
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/g/gevent/gevent-0.13.6.tar.gz#md5=7c836ce2315d44ba0af6134efbcd38c9
Processing gevent-0.13.6.tar.gz
Running gevent-0.13.6/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-zChaNp/gevent-0.13.6/egg-dist-tmp-cPxcYh
In file included from gevent/core.c:225:
gevent/libevent.h:9: fatal error: event.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
tgarv@tommy-Studio-1537:~/Desktop/Code$
```

I also get the same error when trying pip install, so I'm a bit clueless about what to do next. The output says "gevent-websocket 0.3.4 is already the active version in easy-install.pth" and I'm not sure what this means, but I do know that if I try to import gevent or geventwebsocket, it says the module doesn't exist.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> ```
> gevent/libevent.h:9: fatal error: event.h: No such file or directory
> ```

Install the libevent development package for your distro.

Under Ubuntu, it's `libevent-dev`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are on Ubuntu type the following:

```
 sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
 pip install gevent
```

Answer (score 0):

[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)

Step - 1
Go to this website page and look for gevent.whl file according to your python version
and download it.

Step - 2
In command prompt,
Change directory to downloaded gevent.whl file,and copy under format..
C:\Users\ACER\Download>pip install .\gevent.whl

Step - 3
In python shell,
Try it out like "import gevent"..
I think it will work! Be successful...